# Selenium stop working after a period of time

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to extract the data which has 9000 pages. After extracting approx 1700 pages it stopped working when I want it to continue, it starts from  the beginning and execute after approx 1000 pages. In this code, I have to select the zone manually. How  do I scrap data of total pages? Is there any time limitation of chromedriver (for session)?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import csv

url = "https://www.mcg.gov.in/default1.aspx?HTT=B"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'D:/Python_module/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(4)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="CphContentPlaceHolderbody_mcg"]/section/div[1]/div/a[1]/div').click()
time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="CphContentPlaceHolderbody_lnkViewSurveyDataBtn"]').click()
time.sleep(4)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="CphContentPlaceHolderbody_PropertySearchControl1_btnSearch"]').click()
time.sleep(4)


#-----------------This is for extracting the data of page-1-----------------------------------

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="form"]/div[4]/div[11]/table/tbody/tr/td[12]/a').click()
time.sleep(1)
print("If you are in second page then the code is fine.")
soup =  BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
current_url = driver.current_url
table =  soup.find('table', {'class':'table table-hover table-bordered'})

#divs = soup.find('div', {'id':'CphContentPlaceHolderbody_PropertySearchControl1_upTop'})
print(table)

for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
    raw_data = row.findAll('td')[0:]
    property_id = raw_data[0].text
    ward_no = raw_data[1].text
    owner = raw_data[2].text
    print(owner)

page_no = page_no+1

try:    
    while True:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="form"]/div[4]/div[11]/table/tbody/tr/td[14]/a').click()
        time.sleep(1)
        print("If you are in second page then the code is fine.")

        soup =  BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        current_url = driver.current_url
        table =  soup.find('table', {'class':'table table-hover table-bordered'})
        #divs = soup.find('div', {'id':'CphContentPlaceHolderbody_PropertySearchControl1_upTop'})
        #print(table)

        for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
            raw_data = row.findAll('td')[0:]
            property_id = raw_data[0].text
            ward_no = raw_data[1].text
            owner = raw_data[2].text
            print(owner)
        page_no = page_no+1         
except: 
    while True:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="form"]/div[4]/div[11]/table/tbody/tr/td[19]/a').click()
        time.sleep(1)
        print("If you are in second page then the code is fine.")

        soup =  BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        current_url = driver.current_url
        table =  soup.find('table', {'class':'table table-hover table-bordered'})
        #divs = soup.find('div', {'id':'CphContentPlaceHolderbody_PropertySearchControl1_upTop'})
        #print(table)

        for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
            raw_data = row.findAll('td')[0:]
            owner = raw_data[2].text
            print(owner)
        page_no = page_no+1

print("Successfully scrap the data")
driver.quit()
```

it gives the following Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\C Folder\program\scrap\scrap_mcg.py", line 64, in <module>
        element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="form"]/div[4]/div[11]/table/tbody/tr/td[14]/a')))
      File "C:\Users\asn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
        raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 


    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\C Folder\program\scrap\scrap_mcg.py", line 90, in <module>
        soup =  BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
      File "C:\Users\asn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 670, in page_source
        return self.execute(Command.GET_PAGE_SOURCE)['value']
      File "C:\Users\asn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
        self.error_handler.check_response(response)
      File "C:\Users\asn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
        raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window: target window already closed
    from unknown error: web view not found
      (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

Comment: Is there any error you are getting ?

Comment: You are using the last chromedriver and googlechrome is updated?

Comment: I don't have exact which show that time, but it's a kind of 'session_info'

Comment: I am using chromedriver 2.37. and last release is 2.42, if i use 2.42 is it solve the issue?

Comment: 9000 pages is huge. What if you run out of memory after fetching 1700 pages?

Comment: It doesn't show out of memory Error

Comment: It shows the element you have programmed to be clicked is not ready. This is usually what happens when an element is loaded by AJAX later than you expected. Rather than sleeping, you can [explicitly wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) for an element to show up, which will be more consistent than simply `sleep`ing.

Comment: From what I can see, the error occurs on the line at which `//*[@id="form"]/div[4]/div[11]/table/tbody/tr/td[19]/a` selector is. And right after you were `sleep`ing for 1 second. Change that sleeping behavior to either (as i told earlier) to explicit wait or longer sleep (like 2 seconds or more). Even if you change it to longer sleep, you cannot be sure. Safe to use explicit waits here.

Answer (score 0):

> title=" Next to Page 336">... is not clickable at point (988,
>   604). Other element would receive the click: ...

As the error says, the element cannot accept the click.
Can be various amount of things blocking the element being clicked.

- Element is not visible yet.
- Due delay of page load, element is not being fully loaded yet.
- Element is being wrapped, the wrapper is blocking the click.

Several approaches to debug the issue:

- Try with wait. Ex: waitforelementtobeclickable after that execute click method.
- Click the button with javascript code, there is plenty of examples
  around.
- Put check for ajax loader or other custom loader on the page.
- Change/Improve the locator.
- Work with exception handlers, try{} catch{} to execute the click again or
  something else so it can recover not start from the beginning.

If there is something else that we can help, please let us know.